# Configuring NetworkManager to use systemd-resolved without dnsmasq in 17.04

Tags: network-manager, dns, dnsmasq, systemd-resolved

After upgrading to 17.04 from 16.04 I can't figure out how host name resolution system is meant to be configured.

First, I've noticed that after upgrade search domains have disappeared from `/etc/resolv.conf`. They came back once I've removed `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink and restarted NetworkManager. But then the contents became as follows:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search mydomain1 mydomain2
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Ok, search domains are there. But why nameserver 127.0.1.1 is there? No process is listening on that address, hence the name resolution doesn't work.

AFAIK, 127.0.1.1 is the hard-coded listen address of dnsmasq, which is not configured in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[logging]
level=DEBUG
```

Actually, dnsmasq wasn't even installed after upgrade. After installing dnsmasq and adding the line `dns=dnsmasq` into `NetworkManager.conf`, everything works well, but I wonder if I am doing something wrong, or is it a bug in NetworkManager or somewhere else.

So my questions are, is it possible to use systemd-resolved instead of dnsmasq? If not, what is the purpose of moving to systemd-resolved?

Comment: Argh! Undo all of the dnsmasq mods that you've done. DON'T manually edit /etc/resolv.conf (and don't delete any symlinks). Put it all back together the way it was, and if need be, troubleshoot the original configuration. resolv.conf should show `nameserver 127.0.0.53`. Most of the time, just properly configuring your network connection via the GUI works fine.

Comment: @heynnema, please, could you clarify why I shouldn't remove `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink? (I didn't change contents of the target file). Because as far as I understood from `man 5 networkmanager.conf`, as well as from other answers on this site, NetworkManager will create another symlink to the proper destination.

If I'll do as you suggest, I'll get back to the problem I had in the first place -- there won't be any search domains obtained via DHCP. This is actually the problem I've been trying to solve.

Comment: The first thing most people do when they have networking issues is to mess with resolv.conf... and they edit the file even though it says not to... right in the file. If you put it all back to the way it shipped, and edit the network connection profile via the GUI, there's a field there for domains.

Comment: @heynnema 1. I said that I didn't edit the /etc/resolv.conf. 2. I don't want static domain configuration, I want them to be obtained automatically via DHCP, as it has been done in 16.04.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded a little grumpy... maybe my coffee hasn't kicked in yet. I don't know the answer for your original problem then. Sorry.

Comment: any updates? I have same issue. NS obtained by DHCP are not written by NetworkManager...

Comment: Nah. I simply installed dnsmasq and configured NM to use it instead of systemd-resolved and it worked. Looks like it is one of many bugs in recent Ubuntu releases.